# "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, selenium, bugzilla

Below is my code to integrate with bugzilla and i am getting exception

```
import java.util.Map;
import com.j2bugzilla.base.Bug;
import com.j2bugzilla.base.BugFactory;
import com.j2bugzilla.base.BugzillaConnector;
import com.j2bugzilla.base.BugzillaMethod;
import com.j2bugzilla.rpc.LogIn;
import com.j2bugzilla.rpc.ReportBug;


public class bugzillaTest {


public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


//try to connect to bugzilla

BugzillaConnector conn;
conn=new BugzillaConnector();
conn.connectTo("http://bugzilllaurl");


LogIn login=new LogIn("pramod.kg","123#er");
conn.executeMethod(login);

int id=login.getUserID();
System.out.println("current user id"+id);

BugFactory factory=new BugFactory();


              String component="Usability";
              String description="this is a test desc";
              String os="All";
              String platform="PC";
              String priority="High";
              String product="MMNR7";
              String summary="test summary";
              String version="1.0";
   Bug bugs= factory.newBug()
             .setComponent(component)
                     .setDescription(description)
             .setOperatingSystem(os)
             .setPlatform(platform)
              .setPriority(priority)
              .setProduct(product)
              .setSummary(summary)
              .setVersion(version)
              .createBug();

       ReportBug report=new ReportBug(bugs);



          try {

              conn.executeMethod(report);
              System.out.println("Bug is logged!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

            System.out.println("eror"+e.getMessage());
        }
}
}
```

Exception is :

I have scucessfully logged in but when i run **conn.executeMethod(report);** i get below error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlrpc.parser.XmlRpcResponseParser.getErrorCause()Ljava/lang/Throwable;
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.readResponse(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:195)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcStreamTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcStreamTransport.java:156)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcHttpTransport.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.sendRequest(XmlRpcSunHttpTransport.java:69)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:56)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:167)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:137)
    at org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:126)
    at com.j2bugzilla.base.BugzillaConnector.executeMethod(BugzillaConnector.java:164)
    at bugzillaTest.main(bugzillaTest.java:92)

Comment: Please make this question readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

l got fix this issue as below

```
public class bugzillaTest {


private static final String COMP = "Usability";
private static final String DES = "this is a test desc";
private static final String OS = "All";
private static final String PLAT = "PC";
private static final String PRIO = "High";
private static final String PRO = "MMNR7";
private static final String SUM = "test summary";
private static final String VER = "1.0";





public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    // try to connect to bugzilla

    BugzillaConnector conn;
    BugFactory factory;
    Bug bugs;
    ReportBug report;

    conn = new BugzillaConnector();


    conn.connectTo("http://192.168.0.31/");

    LogIn login = new LogIn("username", "password");


    // create a bug

     factory = new BugFactory();
     bugs = factory
                .newBug().
     setOperatingSystem(OS)
        .setPlatform(PLAT)
        .setPriority(PRIO)
        .setProduct(PRO)
        .setComponent(COMP)
        .setSummary(SUM)
        .setVersion(VER)
        .setDescription(DES)
        .createBug();


     report=new ReportBug(bugs);




try{conn.executeMethod(login);
conn.executeMethod(report);

}
catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}


}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add all the below jars and check

xmlrpc-client-3.1.3

xmlrpc-common-3.1.3

xmlrpc-server-3.1.3

Comment: Add ws-commons-util jar and check, it is working for me. I have tried with the code you given working fine.

Please let me know if it works 

Note: make sure you are providing valid details in "bugzillaurl","username","Password"

Comment: @ Sravan , unfortunately now i am getting issue that my login credantials are incorrct.But at  same time i can log in to bugzilla with same username and password through browser.

Comment: That is really strange @Pramod , No Idea seems there might be a minor issue with your code can you recheck it or else post your total code, will check

Comment: replace 
LogIn login=new LogIn(,"pramod.kg","123#er"); with

LogIn login=new LogIn("pramod.kg","123#er");

and 


Whats the status when you replace     int id=login.getUserID(); with    conn.executeMethod(login);

Seems initially you used conn.executeMethod(login); right ?

Comment: sravan, i have updated as you said still login issue is what i am obtaining.Is it because as said in the j2bugzilla site, "Remember, your Bugzilla installation must have the optional Perl modules installed for XML-RPC calls."

Comment: No idea @Pramod, Can u share me the link, Please let me know if you are able to solve the issue. I am using Bugzilla 4.0 if you don't have any issue to use this try with 4.0